# Regex date formats

Tags: regex

I need help with with three regular expressions for date validation. The date formats to validate against should be:
- MMyy
- ddMMyy
- ddMMyyyy

Further:
I want the regular expressions to match the exact number of digits in the formats above. For instance, January should be 01, NOT 1:

060117 // ddMMyy format: Ok
06117 // ddMMyy format: NOT Ok

Hyphens and slashes are NOT allowed, like: 06-01-17, or 06/01/17.

Below are the regex:es that I use. I cannot get them quite right though.

```
string regex_MMyy = @"^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)(\d{2})$";    
string regex_ddMMyy = @"^(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)(\d{2})$";
string regex_ddMMyyyy = @"^(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)(\d{4})$";

var test_MMyy_1 = Regex.IsMatch("0617", regex_MMyy); // Pass
var test_MMyy_2 = Regex.IsMatch("617", regex_MMyy);  // Pass, do NOT want this to pass.
var test_ddMMyy_1 = Regex.IsMatch("060117", regex_ddMMyy); // Pass
var test_ddMMyy_2 = Regex.IsMatch("06117", regex_ddMMyy);  // Pass, do NOT want this to pass.
var test_ddMMyyyy_1 = Regex.IsMatch("06012017", regex_ddMMyyyy); // Pass
var test_ddMMyyyy_2 = Regex.IsMatch("0612017", regex_ddMMyyyy); // Pass, do NOT want this to pass.
```

(If anyone could take allowed days for each month, and leap years into account, that would be a huge bonus :)).

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: A regex can not be used for date-validation. Same as for email-adresses or websites it can only be used to validate a *date-like format*. Even if `2017-02-31` would have a valid format - it is an invalid date, as february  only has 28 days this year. You should better use the `date-parsing` available in your programing language.

Comment: If you don't want to accept single digits, remove all the occurences of `|\d` from your patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that straight away.

Comment: @Rawing The regex:es work fine now. Thanks a lot. Didn't get the meaning of |\d.

Comment: Covering valid number of days a month results in a very long RegExp which is not an applicable solution. You'd better keep with Date data-type & related methods.

Comment: In addition to that, there is NO way to validate strings against leap years, other than literally listing them from the beginning of the time to the end. I'm sure you won't like it